Qualitative confusion about whispering gallery modes
I've been trying to wrap my brain around aspects of whispering gallery modes for a while now (in a qualitative sense, I'm not trying to solve for anything yet).
So, a whispering gallery mode is a pseudo-1D standing wave confined inside an axisymmetric system. As such, it has nodes and antinodes. So far so good.
What confuses me is the axisymmetric property should (?) lead to an infinite rotational degeneracy.
For example, imagine a perfectly reflective ring containing EM radiation in a whispering gallery mode. Even if the light is reflected perfectly, it exerts a pressure on the ring which varies spatially. But, what if we filled the ring with the degenerate modes? So, the same node spacing but different spatial phase. If this is possible (maybe it isn't?) the EM field should (?) be uniform at the ring boundary. I'm having a hard time seeing why it isn't zero. But if it is zero, wouldn't that mean there's no energy at all? And furthermore, filling the ring with light should increase the radiation pressure, right?
I know there's something I'm missing, but could someone clarify what? Is there a reason we can't add photons with arbitrary location and phase so that the superposition of modes is axisymmetric?

Your assumption of infinite degeneracy is wrong. Multiplying your mode by a phase is enough to rotate it, so you do not need infinitely degenerate modes, you just need two independent ones which span a subspace invariant by rotation. In the limit of infinite radius, this is the same as how translation invariance does not lead to infinite degeneracy.
In simple models, even if the field has spatial modulations and nodes, the pressure can still be uniform. Indeed energy and pressure are quadratic quantities of the field, and can be constant despite the nodes of the field.
Take for example a (real) scalar model of EM waves given by d'Alembert's equation:
$$
\partial_t^2\phi-\partial_\theta^2\phi = 0
$$
with $\theta$ the angle along a ring of radius $1$ and $\phi$ the scalar field. In this 1D system, the energy is given by:
$$
e=\frac12\partial_t\phi^2+\frac12\partial_\theta\phi^2
$$
A possible basis of mode is:
$$
\phi^+_m = \cos(m\theta-\omega t)\\
\phi^-_m = \sin(m\theta-\omega t)
$$
with $m\in\mathbb N$ giving the number of nodes. From the equation of motion:
$$
\omega = \pm m
$$
For given $m$, $\phi^+_m, \phi^-_m$ span a subspace invariant by rotation. Therefore, if you superpose many modes with $m$ nodes, you will still end up with a resulting field with $m$ modes. Note that this assumes coherent superposition. For incoherent superposition, due to statistical fluctuations, you will indeed blur out the modes and tend to a uniform field. But even for incoherent superposition, even if the field has zero mean, its fluctuations still give a non zero uniform expected energy. In fact, you can also check that any field in the $m$ subspace has uniform energy. However, the pressure is concentrate at the antinodes, given by the formula:
$$
p = \frac12\phi^2
$$
The previous model is highly idealised, assuming perfect confinement of the wave along the boundary. A more realistic simple model would be to consider a disk domain of radius $1$:
$$
\partial_t^2\phi-\Delta\phi := \partial_t^2\phi-\partial_r^2\phi-\frac1{r^2}\partial_\theta^2\phi = 0
$$
with the basis:
$$
\phi^+_{nm} = \cos(m\theta-\omega t)J_m(j_{nm}r)\\
\phi^-_{nm} = \sin(m\theta-\omega t)J_m(j_{nm}r)
$$
with $r$ the radial coordinate, $J_m$ the $m$-th Bessel function of the first kind and $j_{nm}$ its $n$-th positive zero. For large $m$ and low $n$ (many angular modes and few radial nodes) you get your whispering gallery modes concentrated at the boundary. This time, the dispersion is rather:
$$
\omega = \pm j_{nm}
$$
but the previous analysis still holds with the 2D energy density and pressure at the boundary:
$$
e = \frac12\partial_t\phi^2+\frac12\nabla\phi^2 = \frac12\partial_t\phi^2+\frac12\partial_r\phi^2+\frac1{2r^2}\partial_\theta\phi \\
p = \partial_r\phi^2+\frac12\partial_t\phi^2-\frac12\nabla\phi^2 = \frac12\partial_t\phi^2+\frac12\partial_r\phi^2-\frac1{2r^2}\partial_\theta\phi^2
$$

Ok, I think I follow at least the first part -- had to go back to forgotten trigonometry lore but since any arbitrary phased sine wave can be represented as a sum of unphased sine and cosine waves, adding waves of arbitrary phase will still lead to a sequence of nodes and antinodes (assuming coherence)

Still not quite across the pressure -- if we take your formula for the 1D model it gives a sinusoid of twice the frequency (so time+space averaged to 0). My intuition wants to believe that the pressure should be always nonnegative, since the reflection of photons (even through a shallow angle) imparts momentum, is this a model limitation or something I'm still not grasping?

Yes, you are absolutely right, it bugged me too. Just realised I made a mistake in the math, now everything is consistent.

Thanks for that! That now clicks intuitively. A point of clarification though -- you say the pressure "can" be uniform. In what circumstances does that happen? I've been reading through this paper https://opg.optica.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-15-25-17172&id=148383 and there's an equation in-text in the paragraph before (12) where it seems this is the case. I don't have the background to figure out how either this or your equation were derived though, not sure where to begin?
